# Node-RED Dashboard - Atualizar switch dinâmicamente

Tags: node.js

Estou criando um dashboard de IOT para controlar alguns eletrônicos em minha casa. Para isso, estou usando o NodeRED e o Dashboard.

Uma dúvida que tenho: minha interface possui varios botões do tipo Switch que ja funcionam normalmente. Mas gostaria de criar um outro Switch que atualiza todos os outros botões (algo como ligar/desligar tudo - exemplo do ligado no quarto). Porém, não consigo fazê-lo funcionar.

Há algum segredo para tal?

[image: Imagem do fluxo]

Comment: Sugiro que coloque a sua pergunta no site da Stack focado em IOT https://iot.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! Vou postar lá!

Answer (score -2):

Olá, simplesmente use como entrada de todos os outros o mesmo switch. Se quer mandar um comando para cada um no "setURL", pode usar o topic para cada dos switchs (existem muitas formas de fazer, mas não está claro em sua pergunta o que faz depois do swiths, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[{"id":"718b9c8e.847c84","type":"ui_switch","z":"6fef7876.3be228","name":"","label":"General","tooltip":"","group":"c6dfe18a.81cda","order":0,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"topic","topicType":"msg","style":"","onvalue":"true","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"false","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","animate":false,"x":100,"y":140,"wires":[["1940632.fc91e9d","f4623a0f.59af68","93ccc693.d31b68"]]},{"id":"1940632.fc91e9d","type":"ui_switch","z":"6fef7876.3be228","name":"","label":"Entrada","tooltip":"","group":"c6dfe18a.81cda","order":1,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"Entrada","topicType":"str","style":"","onvalue":"true","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"false","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","animate":false,"x":350,"y":80,"wires":[["9be40143.d1876"]]},{"id":"f4623a0f.59af68","type":"ui_switch","z":"6fef7876.3be228","name":"","label":"Sala","tooltip":"","group":"c6dfe18a.81cda","order":2,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"Sala","topicType":"str","style":"","onvalue":"true","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"false","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","animate":false,"x":340,"y":140,"wires":[["9be40143.d1876"]]},{"id":"93ccc693.d31b68","type":"ui_switch","z":"6fef7876.3be228","name":"","label":"Mesa","tooltip":"","group":"c6dfe18a.81cda","order":3,"width":0,"height":0,"passthru":true,"decouple":"false","topic":"Mesa","topicType":"str","style":"","onvalue":"true","onvalueType":"bool","onicon":"","oncolor":"","offvalue":"false","offvalueType":"bool","officon":"","offcolor":"","animate":false,"x":340,"y":220,"wires":[["9be40143.d1876"]]},{"id":"9be40143.d1876","type":"change","z":"6fef7876.3be228","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"ligado","pt":"msg","to":"payload","tot":"msg"},{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"topic","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":590,"y":160,"wires":[["7a5729a9.0076c8"]]},{"id":"7a5729a9.0076c8","type":"debug","z":"6fef7876.3be228","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"true","targetType":"full","statusVal":"","statusType":"auto","x":830,"y":160,"wires":[]},{"id":"c6dfe18a.81cda","type":"ui_group","name":"Switch","tab":"5e254fe7.cbb43","order":1,"disp":true,"width":"6","collapse":false},{"id":"5e254fe7.cbb43","type":"ui_tab","name":"StackOverFlow","icon":"dashboard","disabled":false,"hidden":false}]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).